# Error in Toast with null

Tags: android, toast

My code is like this

```
public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, dbname, null, dbversion);
    try{
      db=getWritableDatabase();
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      if (db.isOpen()){
        Toast.makeText(null, "Database is open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else {      
        Toast.makeText(null, "Database is Closed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      Log.e(dbname, e.getMessage());        
    }
}
```

I am getting exception a toast and log cat shows

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.manager/com.example.manager.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Comment: you cant pass null as context, instead of null use getApplicationContext or context or this or classname.this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
 Toast.makeText(null, "Database is open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to this

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Database is open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
 toast.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Toast.makeText(null, "Database is open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Put :

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Database is open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thanks  this worked.... But can you please explain me what went wrong and how context solved the problem.

Comment: I refer you to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android

Comment: Thanks ZouZou I am searching it for quite long time now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

@siva     Toast.makeText has first parameter for Contex(android.content) which can be your created context in the application. Sometimes getApplicationContext(),getBasecontext()  is also generally used,second parameter is for String, third parameter is for duration

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

and 
stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android  as posted by ZouZou